# Geolocation google maps with clicking on the map rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I'm trying to store the location of local business on my app by allowing users to click on the google maps and mark where their business is but I am having a hard time trying to get this done.

Which gems do you recommend for me to do this.

on the form I just want the user to click on the map and that location to be saved in the database.

I know [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/) is nice to get the latitude and longitude by typing the address, but I don't want the user to type the address manually I just want them to click on the map.

I've tried this other gem [address_picker-rails](https://github.com/ddidier/address_picker-rails) but it gives me the error when trying to bundle install `address_picker-rails (>= 0) ruby depends on rails (~> 3.2.0) ruby`

Thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at https://github.com/amuntasim/gmap_coordinates_picker? Actually, is there a reason you can't just use a Google Maps onclick event, get the lat/long, and pass that to the database?

Comment: @not_a_bot this is actually the first time I've worked with google maps on a project, if your so kind to link me to it I would be grateful. Also, I tried that gmaps_coordinates_picker gem but I was getting a weird error, I'll try again and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: @not_a_bot I was using the gem that you mentioned, got it setup and everything but the map isn't loading cause of a `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` which is quite weird since I have the `//= require jquery` as first on the `application.js` file

Comment: Did you remember to add a <script> tag for jQuery? You need to include the standard jQuery library before including any plugins that use it.

Comment: @not_a_bot was able to just put in the CDN for the jquery on the div tag before putting the gmaps and that did the trick. I am able to store the latitude and longitude now successfully. Thanks